# Installing wondershaper on Debian 10

Tags: tc

```
# apt-get install wondershaper
# wondershaper wlan0 24000 16000
```

Now what?!

- How can I tell if it's running?
- How can I get it to start automatically after a reboot? (And configure it.)

None of the configuration files that I see mentioned exist (the directory `/etc/conf.d` doesn't even exist), and there is nothing under `/etc/init.d` and I don't understand `systemd` but it doesn't seem to be there either:

```
# systemctl start wondershaper
Failed to start wondershaper.service: Unit wondershaper.service not found.
```

Comment: Don't install wondershaper.

Comment: Why not? What _should_ I be using for QoS?

Comment: Anyway Debian's version is *old* (1.1a dating back from 2004 or before). The one on github has been heavily changed since (including the syntax of the command) with multiple improvements (IFB to allow pseudo-shaping on ingress, CBQ -> HTB etc.). Try https://github.com/magnific0/wondershaper/

Comment: I'm sure it's better than anything I could write myself using `tc`. I'll give it a go...

I've seen `up` and `down` commands being added to `/etc/network/interfaces`. Is that the right way to start it automatically?

Comment: It's a fire-and-forget shell script. Like having firewall rules. Once tc rules are loaded they stay. You'll have to figure out yourself where or when to run it, nothing was made about this.

Comment: I thought `iptables` rules were wiped at reboot and you have to use package  `iptables-persistent`?

Comment: That's correct disappears at reboot. Doesn't change my previous comment.

Comment: The statement "Once tc rules are loaded they stay." made me think that you were saying that they'd survive a reboot. I'll try `up` in `/etc/network/interfaces` then...

Comment: After installing `wondershaper` from git the network completely broke. Had to re-install Debian. Next time after installing I could still ping 8.8.8.8 but could not ssh into the machine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Installing from current source:

```
# apt-get purge wondershaper
# cd
# mkdir wondershaper
# git clone https://github.com/magnific0/wondershaper.git
# cd wondershaper
# make install
# vi /etc/systemd/wondershaper.conf
# systemctl enable --now wondershaper.service
```

When running on the external (Internet connection) interface I found that internal SSH traffic was laggy while large file copies were in progress. Therefore I switched to running in on the internal network and my feeling is that this is working.

`/etc/systemd/wondershaper.conf`

```
IFACE="br0"

# Download rate in Kbps
DSPEED="1000000"

# Upload rate in Kbps
USPEED="1000000"
```